# PageSpeed Insights - No FID data for mobile

Tags: pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed Insights doesn't show FID data for mobile on a particular URL I am testing (see attached)[pagespeed insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YV8K.png). Where else can I find FID data?

Answer (score 0):

The "Field Data" will only show when there are enough visits to the page stored in the CrUX dataset.

As that page has not had enough visits yet you have to resort to other methods to estimate FID.

As it is not possible to measure FID without a real human interacting with the page, the Lab tests use [Total Blocking Time (TBT)](https://web.dev/tbt/) as a very close approximation and you should use that.

> FID requires a real user and thus cannot be measured in the lab. However, the Total Blocking Time (TBT) metric is lab-measurable, correlates well with FID in the field, and also captures issues that affect interactivity. Optimizations that improve TBT in the lab should also improve FID for your users.

Taken from: https://web.dev/fid/

Comment: Thank you Graham. I later found this information. I will TBT is a measurement.